# Removing scroll from page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using JqueryMobile and I have noticed a vertical scroll bar on all my pages (except the first page) which I have no idea why it is happening.

On one of my pages, I have a couple of buttons and that is all. It takes up about 1/4 of the page and there is a vertical scroll bar being shown.

Any ideas on how to work out why it is there and how to remove it?

JD.

Comment: We're going to need to see some code (relevant HTML/CSS) to help you out here :) could be any number of things.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following css

```
body{
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Comment: That did not work. Any why I can track down what is causing it?

Comment: do you have a demo link that we can have a look at ?

Comment: Unfortunately the network here is all tied down, need approval in the states and then a few months of paperwork to allow access. Clyde, do you use any tools to look at Css that may help?

Comment: Well , you're developing for a mobile site , which I haven't yet done.
What browser are you testing in ?

Comment: Chrome currently. I was pretty sure I had the same problem in Firefox but just checked and there are no scroll bars there at all (I am still pretty new to css/jquery/jQM, so still trying to get a hang of how it all works).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag